# Windows Neo4j cannot create graph with 25000 nodes due to memory error

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a graph on a Windows machine with 350,000 nodes - unfortunately i cannot even create one with 25,000 nodes.  500 nodes works.  With 25,000 it runs for 20 mins and then gives a Java heap error.

Below is the cypher script and in the csv file i control the number of rows (would like to do 350K).  Error I get is Java heap - i tried increasing memory config to 1024, didn't help and it wouldn't let me increase to 2048.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (f:F { name: csvLine.f })
MERGE (s:S { name: csvLine.s })
MERGE (t:T { name: csvLine.t })
MERGE (region:R { name: csvLine.r })
CREATE (d:D { name: csvLine.name})
CREATE (d)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(f)
CREATE (f)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(r)
CREATE (d)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(s)
CREATE (d)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(t)
CREATE (s)-[:PINGS{c: toInt(csvLine.c)}]->(t)
```

Comment: Which version are you using? Try to update to 2.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to do three things

1. Update to Neo4j 2.1.3
2. **Create the necessary indexes**
3. Simplify your statements into multiple simpler ones.
   The reason being that Cypher (when you match + create data) has to pull in all merge/match statemets in upfront to be not affected by data created later on.

---

```
 USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
 MERGE (f:F { name: csvLine.f });


USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (s:S { name: csvLine.s });

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (t:T { name: csvLine.t });

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (region:R { name: csvLine.r });

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
CREATE (d:D { name: csvLine.name});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
MATCH (f:F { name: csvLine.f })
MATCH (s:S { name: csvLine.s })
MATCH (t:T { name: csvLine.t })
MATCH (region:R { name: csvLine.r })
MATCH (d:D { name: csvLine.name})
CREATE (d)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(f)
CREATE (f)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(r)
CREATE (d)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(s)
CREATE (d)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(t)
CREATE (s)-[:PINGS{c: toInt(csvLine.c)}]->(t);
```

For the first ones you can also use this construct if you only import a single file (these will be faster)

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:c:...my file.csv" AS csvLine
WITH distinct csvLine.f as csv_f
CREATE (f:F { name: csv_f });
```

etc.